# Получил рабочий код на Kotlin, прошу знающего человека перевести данный код в Java

Tags: java, android

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val SELECT_PHOTO = 1234

lateinit var prefernces: SharedPreferences

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    prefernces = getSharedPreferences("APP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    val uriString = prefernces.getString("image_uri", "")

    if (uriString != null) {
        iv_test.setImageBitmap(bitmapFromUri(Uri.parse(uriString)))
    }

    btn_pick.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intent.setType("image/*")
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO)
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        iv_test.setImageURI(data?.data)
        prefernces.edit().putString("image_uri", data?.data.toString()).apply()
    }


}

private fun bitmapFromUri(uri: Uri): Bitmap? =
    contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")?.fileDescriptor?.let {
        BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: а в чем смысл перехода с kotlin на java?

Comment: Нет-нет, я не перехожу с kotlin на java, просто я получил ответ на свой вопрос на языке kotlin, а мой код написан на Java. Соответственно мне, для того чтобы добавить это к себе нужно сначала получить этот же код на Java

Comment: странная система, о каком вопросе идет речь, и почему не перейти на kotlin полностью?

Comment: Потому что я сейчас только начал изучать Java, понятно, что куда проще, но переходить на него сейчас мне будет неудобно

Comment: @Denis Котлин полностью совместим с java. Можете просто использовать классы и файлы kotlin в java проектах и наоборот.

Comment: Могу я вас попросить перевести только последние 3 строки (bimapFromUri)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы конвертировать `Kotlin` в `Java` нужно сделать:

1. Перейти - `Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode`
2. Дальше нажмите `Decompile`
3. Используйте получившийся Java код.

Так же добавлю [сервис](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Java%20to%20Kotlin%20conversion/Task.kt) от создателей языка программирования `Kotlin` есть такой сервис который делает то что вам нужно но наоборот то есть конвертируют `Java` в `Kotlin` который иногда мне помогает. Так же если все-таки созреете для перехода на котлин то в Android Studio можно все конвертировать автоматически. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file) есть источник где написано как решить вашу проблему разными способами.